# Slide function on mobile for toggle slider?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a jQuery toggle that switches content on my page. I would like to be able to slide it left and right on mobile, is there any way to do this? Code below

```
<label class="toggle-label toggler" id="toggle"><input id="rdb1" type="checkbox" name="toggler" checked="true"/><span class='back'>
<span class='toggle'></span>
<span class='label on'>Option One</span>  
<span class='label off'>Option Two</span>
</span></label>

<div id="blk-1" class="toHide">
Content One
</div>

<div id="blk-2" class="toHide" style="display:none">
Content Two
</div>

  $("[name=toggler]").click(function() {
  $('.toHide').hide();
  var toShow = $(this).is(":checked") ? "blk-1" : "blk-2";
 $("#" + toShow).toggle(1);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gabbymarley/7qo0ksab/1/ Here is a fiddle of the code

Comment: If jQuery UI is an option, you can use : https://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=UI/Effects/Slide&redirect=no

Comment: Seems like it's sliding my whole toggle and not just the buttons